# ncurses clear() is not differential

Tags: ncurses

I noticed that function clear() retransmit all screen to terminal instead of transmitting only the differences, as excepted with ncurses.

I'm working with SSH so I can see the difference on a 180x60 terminal :

- with clearing using clear() : 20kB/s
- without clearing : 200B/s

The refresh rate is 0.5s and the differences between each frame is about 20 characters.

How can we explain this and clear screen more efficiently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

> The  clear and wclear routines are like erase and werase, but they also call clearok, so that the screen is cleared completely on the next call to wrefresh for that window and repainted from scratch.

Try `erase()`